# Different NA actions for coefficients and summary of linear model in R

Tags: r, summary, lm, na

In R, when using `lm()`, if I set `na.action = na.pass` inside the call to `lm()`, then in the summary table there is an NA for any coefficient that cannot be estimated (because of missing cells in this case).

If, however, I extract just the coefficients from the summary object, using either `summary(myModel)$coefficients` or `coef(summary(myModel))`, then the NA's are omitted.

I want the NA's to be included when I extract the coefficients the same way that they are included when I print the summary. Is there a way to do this?

Setting `options(na.action = na.pass)` does not seem to help.

Here is an example:

```
> set.seed(534)
> myGroup1 <- factor(c("a","a","a","a","b","b"))
> myGroup2 <- factor(c("first","second","first","second","first","first"))
> myDepVar <- rnorm(6, 0, 1)
> myModel <- lm(myDepVar ~ myGroup1 + myGroup2 + myGroup1:myGroup2)
> summary(myModel)

Call:
lm(formula = myDepVar ~ myGroup1 + myGroup2 + myGroup1:myGroup2)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.05813  0.55323  0.05813 -0.55323 -0.12192  0.12192 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         -0.15150    0.23249  -0.652    0.561
myGroup11            0.03927    0.23249   0.169    0.877
myGroup21           -0.37273    0.23249  -1.603    0.207
myGroup11:myGroup21       NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: 0.465 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.5605,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.2675 
F-statistic: 1.913 on 2 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.2914 

> coef(summary(myModel))
               Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.15149826  0.2324894 -0.6516352 0.5611052
myGroup11    0.03926774  0.2324894  0.1689012 0.8766203
myGroup21   -0.37273117  0.2324894 -1.6032180 0.2072173

> summary(myModel)$coefficients
               Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.15149826  0.2324894 -0.6516352 0.5611052
myGroup11    0.03926774  0.2324894  0.1689012 0.8766203
myGroup21   -0.37273117  0.2324894 -1.6032180 0.2072173
```

Comment: Would you agree that this is a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just extract the coefficients from the fitted model:

```
> coef(myModel)
             (Intercept)                myGroup1b 
             -0.48496169              -0.07853547 
          myGroup2second myGroup1b:myGroup2second 
              0.74546233                       NA
```

That seems the easiest option.

`na.action` has nothing to do with this. Note that you *didn't* pass `na.action = na.pass` in your example.

`na.action` is a global option for handling `NA` in the **data** passed to a model fit, usually in conjunction with a formula; it is also the name of a function `na.action()`. R builds up the so called model frame from the `data` argument and the symbolic representation of the model expressed in the formula. At this point, any `NA` would be detected and the default option for `na.action` is to use `na.omit()` to remove the `NA` from the data by dropping samples with `NA` for any variable. There are alternatives, most usefully `na.exclude()`, which would remove `NA` during fitting but add back `NA` in the correct places in the fitted values, residuals etc. Read `?na.omit` and `?na.action` for more, plus `?options` for more on this.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that the na.action settings aren't relevant to this problem. Extracting the coefficients from the fitted model might work as a last resort, but I wanted to bind a couple of columns for confidence intervals to the summary table. I don't want just the estimates; I want the standard errors, p-values, etc., with confidence intervals attached at the end. I could just make the table from scratch, but I thought there might be some simple setting that needed changing to get `coef(summary(myModel))` and `confint(myModel)` to output the same number of rows in the same order.

Comment: @Jdub, did you figure this out? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: same here ! same problem

Comment: @Jdub isn't this just a matter of saying: `summary(model)[coef(model), ]` where the `NA` argument to `i` of `[` produces a totally `NA` row? I hope that's what you're asking for, because that's the only output that makes sense to me. Otherwise, you may need to describe a bit better what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

the documentation of summary.lm says 'Aliased coefficients are omitted in the return object but restored by the *print* method'. It seems there is no parameter to control this omit. There is another work around besides using coef(summary(myModel)) as suggested by @Gavin Simpson. You can create a matrix

```
nr <- num_regressors - nrow(summary(myModel)$coefficients) ##num_regressors shall be defined previously
nc <- 4
rnames <- names(which(summary(myModel)$aliased))
cnames <- colnames(summary(myModel)$coefficients)
mat_na <- matrix(data = NA,nrow = nr,ncol = nc,
           dimnames = list(rnames,cnames))
```

and then rbind the two matrice:

```
mat_coef <- rbind(summary(myModel)$coefficients,mat_na)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also just transform the summary fit table into a data frame (where the variables that are NA are lost):

```
fit <- as.data.frame(summary(fit)$coefficients)
```

And then extract the coefficients by name:

```
fit["age", "Pr(>|z|)"]
```

If "age" has been dropped, you'll get an NA when trying to extract the P-value for age from the dataframe